# How to extract data from Chrome's \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\preferences file?

Tags: json, google-chrome

Is there a way to extract chrome's preference file from the location \AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\preferences It is in json format, but parsing not happening.

Answer (score 0):

Just open, edit, and save it in "Notepad."
--Personal experience